# Url seems to be repeating

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, razor

I am using asp.net razor engine.  I have a delete button and the first time I press it, it works.  The second time the url repeats the function and does not work.

This is the first time I use the Delete button
[image: This is the first time I use the Delete button]

[image]

This is the second time I use Delete. Notice the URL is del/del.  Trying to avoid that second del.

Here is my controller

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using DapperApp.Factory;
using login.Models;
using login.Controllers;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;


namespace login.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {

        private readonly UserFactory userFactory;

        public HomeController(UserFactory user) {
            userFactory = user;
        }

        // GET: /Home/
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("")]
        public IActionResult Index()
        {

            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [Route("")]
        public IActionResult Register(Home model)
        {
            if(!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return View("Index", model);
            }
            PasswordHasher<Home> Hasher = new PasswordHasher<Home>();
            model.Password = Hasher.HashPassword(model, model.Password);
            userFactory.Add(model);
            TempData["message"] = false;

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [Route("login")]
        public IActionResult Login(Home model)
        {     
            if(model.Password == null || model.Email == null){
                TempData["login"] = false;
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }      
            var pass = userFactory.FindByEmail(model);
            var Hasher = new PasswordHasher<Home>();
            if(pass == null)
            {
                TempData["login"] = false;
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
                // Pass the user object, the hashed password, and the PasswordToCheck
            if(0 != Hasher.VerifyHashedPassword(model, pass.Password, model.Password))
            {
                TempData["first_name"] = pass.First_Name;
                TempData["last_name"] = pass.Last_Name;
                TempData["id"] = pass.Id;
                HttpContext.Session.SetString("Id", pass.Id.ToString());

                ViewBag.Quotes = userFactory.FindAll();
                return View();   
            }
            TempData["login"] = false;

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [Route("addQuote")]
        public IActionResult AddQuote(Quotes model)
        {   
            var test = HttpContext.Session.GetString("Id");
            if(!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                TempData["id"] = test;
                model.Users_id = Convert.ToInt32(test.ToString());
                var user2 = userFactory.FindById(model.Users_id);
                TempData["first_name"] = user2.First_Name;
                TempData["last_name"] = user2.Last_Name;
                ViewBag.Quotes= userFactory.FindAll();
                return View("Login", model);
            }
            if(test == null){
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            model.Users_id = Convert.ToInt32(test.ToString());
            userFactory.addQuote(model);
            var user = userFactory.FindById(model.Users_id);
            TempData["id"] = test;
            TempData["first_name"] = user.First_Name;
            TempData["last_name"] = user.Last_Name;
            ViewBag.Quotes = userFactory.FindAll();
            return View("Login", model);  
        }
        [HttpGet]
         [Route("logout")]
        public IActionResult Logout()
        { 
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [Route("del/{id}")]
        public IActionResult Del(int Id) // This is my delete method
        {
            userFactory.DeleteByID(Id);
             ViewBag.Quotes2= userFactory.FindAll();
             var test = HttpContext.Session.GetString("Id");
             var user = userFactory.FindById(Convert.ToInt32(test));
             TempData["first_name"] = user.First_Name;
            TempData["last_name"] = user.Last_Name;
            TempData["id"] = test;


            return View("Login");
        }   
    }
}
```

Here is my cshtml page

```
<h1>Hello @TempData["first_name"] @TempData["last_name"]</h1>
 @if(TempData["first_name"]!=  null)
 {

 }

 @model login.Models.Quotes
<h1>Add Your Quote</h1>
@using(Html.BeginForm("AddQuote","Home"))
{
    <p>
        <label>Your Quote</label>
        @Html.TextAreaFor(d=>d.quotes)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(d => d.quotes)
    </p>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add my quote!"/>
}

<form action="logout" method="get">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Log Out"/>
</form>

<div >
    @{
        if(ViewBag.Quotes != null)
        {
            foreach(var quotes in ViewBag.Quotes)
            {
                //If there are any errors for a field...

               <p><q>@quotes.quotes</q></p> 
               <p class="wrapper">-@quotes.First_Name @quotes.Last_Name at @quotes.Created_At.ToString("hh"):@quotes.Created_At.ToString("mm")
                     @quotes.Created_At.ToString("tt") @quotes.Created_At.ToString("MMM")  @quotes.Created_At.ToString("dd")
                     @quotes.Created_At.ToString("yyyy")</p>
                if(@quotes.Users_id == Convert.ToInt32(TempData["id"].ToString()))
                {
                    <form action="del/@quotes.Id_Quotes" method="get">
                        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Delete"/>
                    </form> 
                }

            }
        }
        if(ViewBag.Quotes2 != null)
        {
            foreach(var quotes in ViewBag.Quotes2)
            {
                //If there are any errors for a field...

               <p><q>@quotes.quotes</q></p> 
               <p class="wrapper">-@quotes.First_Name @quotes.Last_Name at @quotes.Created_At.ToString("hh"):@quotes.Created_At.ToString("mm")
                     @quotes.Created_At.ToString("tt") @quotes.Created_At.ToString("MMM")  @quotes.Created_At.ToString("dd")
                     @quotes.Created_At.ToString("yyyy")</p>
                if(@quotes.Users_id == Convert.ToInt32(TempData["id"].ToString()))
                {
                    <form action="del/@quotes.Id_Quotes" method="get">
                        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Delete"/>
                    </form> 
                }

            }
        }

    }
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your form action is using a relative (not a concrete) reference, meaning it will append the action to the end of the current url each time you submit the form. Try making the action the absolute url of your get request. In this case that would mean:

```
<form action="del/@quotes.Id_Quotes" method="get">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Delete"/>
</form>
```

becomes

```
<form action="/del/@quotes.Id_Quotes" method="get">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Delete"/>
</form>
```

Also, just to nitpick, when deleting things (or adding and editing things) to a database you should use a POST request. They provide an additional level of security.